# How to set the source port when sending udp packets

Tags: go

On the client, I want to set the UDP source port when sending a udp packet.
On the server, I want to know what the UDP source port was received on.

**Client:**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
)

func main() {

    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", nil, s)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    connection, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

In the above client code, is there a way for me to set the source port?
In the above server code, is there a way for me to know the source port used?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897417/cant-read-udp-reply-golang/40897620#40897620, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483075/golang-readfromudp-behavior-when-source-port-differs-in-reponse-from-dial/32483391#32483391

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialUDP

`func DialUDP(network string, laddr, raddr *UDPAddr) (*UDPConn, error)`

Both laddr and raddr use UDPAddr struct, but you're not setting laddr.

```
laddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "<source_int>:50000")

raddr := net.UDPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP("<dest>"), Port: 50000}

conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", laddr, &raddr)
```

Comment: Once normally wants to use `ListenUDP` rather than `DialUDP`, which lets you write to whatever address you choose, avoids the unusual "connected UDP" socket.

Comment: @alex  of course, thanks, i was setting it to nil. i now set it.    On the server side, is there any way for me to know the source port used to send the udp pkt?

Comment: @jimB I have several clients sending pkts to a single server. I would like to know for each udp pkt which client sent the pkt, so i would like to get the remote addr (ip address and source port) for the sender (client) of the udp pkt

Comment: @RobGoguen: I'm not sure what that has to do with preferring `ListenUDP`. You can see the available methods of a `UDPConn` in the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn.